# Jetty 8 cannot launch java web-app on AWS EC2 server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jetty

I am trying to launch a `war` (dss-server.war) file using Jetty on Ubuntu 13.10 Server using the Amazon EC2 service. The project in question uses maven, java, apache-camel, spring and SIGAR. However the process is killed for no apparent reason at all:

```
Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future
2014-02-26 22:40:48.737:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2014-02-26 22:40:48.798:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /home/ubuntu/jetty-distribution-8.1.14.v20131031/webapps at interval 1
2014-02-26 22:40:48.814:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /home/ubuntu/jetty-distribution-8.1.14.v20131031/webapps/dss-server.war
2014-02-26 22:40:49.096:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/home/ubuntu/jetty-distribution-8.1.14.v20131031/webapps/dss-server.war!/ to /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-dss-server.war-_dss-server-any-/webapp
2014-02-26 22:41:17.170:INFO:dss-server:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2014-02-26 22:41:19.193:INFO:dss-server:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2014-02-26 22:41:32.409:INFO:dss-server:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dss'
Killed
```

I am launching the project using the following command line:

```
java -jar -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M start.jar > output.txt
```

And the output file does not show anything incriminatory as well. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it. The problem lies with OpenJDK. The previous configuration that I have mention will **NOT** work with openJDK (probably because Jetty does not like it). It has to be Java from oracle. I fixed the problem by installing Oracle's Java by following this article:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html